# .NET 6 not showing up with dotnet --info

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

I installed .NET 6 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) and the installation appears to have gone successfully. However, when I run "dotnet --info" it doesn't show up.

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet" --info 
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   3.1.418  Commit:    91fae0d634

Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.19044  OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.418\

Host (useful for support):   Version: 6.0.4   Commit:  be98e88c76

.NET SDKs installed:
  1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.120 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.418 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I already checked the order of the dotnet folders in the PATH environment variable and Program Files shows up before Program Files (x86). In fact, I directly ran the Program Files instance by using the full path (see above).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That page doesn't offer a download for the 6.0 sdk, it assumes you have VS installed.  [Look here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) instead.

Comment: @HansPassant OK I'll try that. I do have Visual Studio 2019 installed but am not using it due to resource constraints. I found that link here, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-for-c-sharp-10-and-net-6-0/, so I assumed it would work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, that worked. If I had paid closer attention I would have realized that I only installed the runtime.